# How to preserve state of activity inside TabHostActivity in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, tabs

Hi i have an android app that looks like this:

[image]

The Home Tab includes a activity and another child activity.
It is a TabHost layout.
The About and Contact activity have only single activity.

When i tap inside Home Tab button i.e. " Open Child " it opens a new activity inside the parent.But when i click the About Tab and come back in Home Tab . The Tab starts from the begining Home Tab only.It does not show the last child activity that was opened before clicking the About Tab Button.

My actual app will be same but will include cascading child activity inside each other.
What i want is that the If i open Home tab > child>another child activity> another child activity , And even i tap About or Contact tab. While taping Home it should start from the last opendactivity ie another child activity.

And i should be able to get back from there to the home activity.

I have added code below Please suggest changes in that.

## AboutActivity.java

```
package com.manish.tabdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AboutActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    }
}
```

## AboutGroupActivity

```
package com.manish.tabdemo;


import com.manish.util.AnimatedActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
`
public class AboutGroupActivity extends AnimatedActivity
{
    public static AboutGroupActivity AboutGroupStack;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AboutGroupStack = AboutGroupActivity.this;

       startChildActivity("AboutGroupActivity", new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
    }
}
```

## ChildrenActivity

```
package com.manish.tabdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ChildActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);
    }
}
```

## ContactActivity.java

```
package com.manish.tabdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ContactActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
    }
}
```

## ContactGroupActivity

```
package com.manish.tabdemo;


import com.manish.util.AnimatedActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ContactGroupActivity extends AnimatedActivity
{
    public static ContactGroupActivity ContactGroupStack;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ContactGroupStack = ContactGroupActivity.this;

       startChildActivity("ContactGroupActivity", new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class));
    }
}
```

## HomeActivity

```
package com.manish.tabdemo;

import com.manish.util.AnimatedActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity{
    Button buttonNext;
    private boolean isClicked=true;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        buttonNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_nxt);
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.e("test", "test");
                AnimatedActivity pActivity = (AnimatedActivity)HomeActivity.this.getParent();                    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
                    pActivity.startChildActivity("home_screen", intent);
                }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        System.out.println("***back*");
        HomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        System.out.println("****event****"+event+"****"+keyCode);
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {

               finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

## HomeGroupActivity.java

```
package com.manish.tabdemo;


import com.manish.util.AnimatedActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HomeGroupActivity extends AnimatedActivity
{
    public static HomeGroupActivity HomeGroupStack;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        HomeGroupStack = HomeGroupActivity.this;

       startChildActivity("HomeGroupActivity", new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
    }
}
```

## TabHostActivity

```
package com.manish.tabdemo;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TextView;



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class TabHostActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener
{ 
 private static final String[] TABS = { "HomeGroupActivity", "AboutGroupActivity", "ContactGroupActivity" };
 private static final String[] TAB_NAMES = { "Home", "About", "Contact"};
 public static TabHost tabs ;
    public static TabWidget tabWidget ;    
 protected Bitmap roundedImage;
    public boolean checkTabsListener = false;


    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {        
     super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_host);

        Bitmap roundedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_tab_background);
        roundedImage = getRoundedCornerBitmap(roundedImage,3);

        tabs = getTabHost();

        tabWidget = tabs.getTabWidget();

     tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

     for (int i = 0; i < TABS.length; i++)
        {
         TabHost.TabSpec tab = tabs.newTabSpec(TABS[i]);

         //Asociating Components
         ComponentName oneActivity = new ComponentName("com.manish.tabdemo", "com.manish.tabdemo." + TABS[i]);
         Intent intent = new Intent().setComponent(oneActivity);           
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         tab.setContent(intent);         
         //Setting the Indicator
         MyTabIndicator myTab = new MyTabIndicator(this, TAB_NAMES[i],(i+1), roundedImage); 
         tab.setIndicator(myTab); 
         tabs.addTab(tab);
        }

     checkTabsListener = true;

        for(int i=0;i<tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
         tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }


  tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);   

  //Maintaining Clicks

  // Home Tab Click

  tabWidget.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {     
     if(HomeGroupActivity.HomeGroupStack != null && HomeGroupActivity.HomeGroupStack.mIdList.size()>1)
     {      
      HomeGroupActivity.HomeGroupStack.getLocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities();
      HomeGroupActivity.HomeGroupStack.mIdList.clear();
      HomeGroupActivity.HomeGroupStack.mIntents.clear();
      HomeGroupActivity.HomeGroupStack.mAnimator.removeAllViews();
     ; HomeGroupActivity.HomeGroupStack.startChildActivity("CareGroupActivity", new Intent(HomeGroupActivity.HomeGroupStack, HomeActivity.class));

     }

     tabWidget.setCurrentTab(0);
     tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
     tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);  
   }
        });


  // About tab Click

  tabWidget.getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
   public void onClick(View v)
   {     
    if(AboutGroupActivity.AboutGroupStack != null && AboutGroupActivity.AboutGroupStack.mIdList.size()>0)
    {
     AboutGroupActivity.AboutGroupStack.getLocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities();
     AboutGroupActivity.AboutGroupStack.mIdList.clear();      
     AboutGroupActivity.AboutGroupStack.mIntents.clear();
     AboutGroupActivity.AboutGroupStack.mAnimator.removeAllViews();            
     AboutGroupActivity.AboutGroupStack.startChildActivity("TrackingGroupActivity", new Intent(AboutGroupActivity.AboutGroupStack, AboutActivity.class));           
    }     

    tabWidget.setCurrentTab(1);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(1);
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);       
   }
        });

  // Contact tab click

  tabWidget.getChildAt(2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
   public void onClick(View v)
   {     
    if(ContactGroupActivity.ContactGroupStack != null && ContactGroupActivity.ContactGroupStack.mIdList.size()>0)
    {

     ContactGroupActivity.ContactGroupStack.getLocalActivityManager().removeAllActivities();
     ContactGroupActivity.ContactGroupStack.mIdList.clear();      
     ContactGroupActivity.ContactGroupStack.mIntents.clear();
     ContactGroupActivity.ContactGroupStack.mAnimator.removeAllViews();            
     ContactGroupActivity.ContactGroupStack.startChildActivity("DashboardGroupActivity", new Intent(ContactGroupActivity.ContactGroupStack, ContactActivity.class));           
    }     

    tabWidget.setCurrentTab(2);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(2);
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);       
   }
        });


    }


    public class MyTabIndicator extends LinearLayout 
    {
  public MyTabIndicator(Context context, String label, int tabId, Bitmap bgImg)
  {
   super(context);
   LinearLayout tab = null;
   TextView tv;
   this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

   if(tabId == 1)
   {
    tab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.home_tab, null);
    tv = (TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    tv.setText(label);
   }



   else if(tabId == 2)
   {
    tab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.about_tab, null);
    tv = (TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    tv.setText(label);
   }
   else if(tabId == 3)
   {
    tab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_tab, null);
    tv = (TextView)tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_label);
    tv.setText(label);
   }

   this.addView(tab, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(320/4,55));   
  }  
    }



 public void onTabChanged(String tabId) 
 {      
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tabs.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

        for(int i=0; i<tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
  {                             
         if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(TABS[i]))
   {            
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_background);     
   }
   else
   {
    tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor((Color.TRANSPARENT));
   }     
    }  
 }

  public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,float roundPxRadius)
 {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx =roundPxRadius;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
 }

 public void onResume()
 {
  super.onResume();


  //ReConstructing TabViews
  reDesignTabViews(); 
 }

 public void onPause()
 {
  super.onPause();     
 }




 /**
  * Method used to re constructing the Views at tab bar. This solves tabs disappearing issue.
  */
 public void reDesignTabViews()
 {
  MyTabIndicator myIndicator;


  //Construction of tab views....
  for(int i=0 ; i< tabWidget.getChildCount() ; i++)
  {
   myIndicator = (MyTabIndicator) tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
   myIndicator.removeAllViews();

   switch (i) 
   {

     case 0:
     myIndicator.addView((LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_tab, null));
     break;
    case 1:    
     myIndicator.addView((LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.about_tab, null));    
     break;
    case 2:    
     myIndicator.addView((LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_tab, null));    
     break;

   }   
  }  
 }

}
```

## AndroidManfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.manish.tabdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.TabHostActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.AboutActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.ContactActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.ChildActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.AboutGroupActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.ContactGroupActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.HomeGroupActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Having activities in tabs has been deprecated for **five years**. Please move to current and supported techniques for tabs, whether based on a `ViewPager` (e.g., `TabLayout`) or not (e.g., `FragmentTabHost`).

Comment: I want to activity inside activity that is requirement. that's why need help in this regard.

Comment: @DeepakDimri that's what `Fragments` are for.

Comment: @CoryCharlton can you share some example for that where we have nested fragments. I also want to Actionbar in top of fragment so that i can move back from the child fragment